# db_condition : nid = tnid

Tags: 7, database

I need to retrieve all nodes whose node ID is equal to their tnid, or whose tnid is equal to 0. I am using the following code.

```
$db_or = db_or();
$db_or->condition('nid','tnid','=');
$db_or->condition('tnid',0,'=');

$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->condition($db_or)
  ->fields('n',array('title','nid','tnid','type','language'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(50)
  ->condition('type','article','=')
  ->orderBy('created', 'DESC');
```

It does not work. It returns 0 node IDs, which is not the expected result, since the following code returns a different result.

```
db_query_range("select * from {node} where (nid = tnid or tnid = 0) and type = 'article' order by created DESC",0,1000);
```

If I remove `$db_or->condition('nid','tnid','=');` the first query returns only nodes with tnid equal to 0.

So, why does the first `OR` condition break my code?

Answer (score 3):

You need a [`where`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/function/DatabaseCondition%3A%3Awhere/7.x), `condition` always uses the value literally:

```
$db_or = db_or();
$db_or->where('nid = tnid');
$db_or->condition('tnid',0,'=');
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you are showing doesn't work because `$db_or->condition('nid','tnid','=');` is comparing the value of the *nid* field with the literal string `'tnid'`, not with the value of the *tnid* field.
When you need a more complex condition, you need to use [`SelectQuery::where()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Awhere/7.x), not [`SelectQuery::condition()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Acondition/7.x).

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n',array('title','nid','tnid','type','language'))
  ->condition('n.type','article','=')
  ->where('n.nid = n.tnid OR n.tnid = 0')
  ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(50);
```

Keep also in mind that, if you don't need to get only the nodes to which the currently logged-in user has access, or your query is not supposed to be altered from other modules, you should use `db_query()`, which is faster than `db_select()`.

In the case you were interested only to the nodes to which the currently logged-in user has access, the code to use should be the following one.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n',array('title','nid','tnid','type','language'))
  ->where('n.nid = n.tnid OR n.tnid = 0')
  ->condition('n.type','article','=')
  ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')
  ->addTag('node_access')
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(50);
```